# How to store LocalTime in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, date, java-8, localtime

I have an entity that has a variable of type `LocalTime` and I would like to store it in database. So I have two questions:

1. What data type will the field in mysql be?
2. What annotation to use for entity?

I do not care for date at all whatsoever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[hibernate-java8](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hibernate%7Chibernate-java8%7C5.1.1.Final%7Cjar) provide a LocalTimeType for persist a `LocalTime` field.Since hibernate-java8-5.2.+  has been merged into the hibernate-core module.

### Usage

saving `LocalTime` as sql time column.

```
@Column
private LocalTime time;
```

saving `LocalTime` as sql varchar column.

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(8)")
private LocalTime time;
```